# How do I design a conceptual lens schematic?

Tags: optics, lens-design, learning

I would like to attempt to create a schematic for a simple or small compound lens, but the process seems very daunting. I have thoroughly read ['Science for the Curious Photographer:
An Introduction to the Science of Photography'](http://books.google.com/books?id=s3dLAQAAIAAJ&q=science+for+the+curious+photographer&dq=science+for+the+curious+photographer&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bi-GT4C1PImTiQLxu43xDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA), and fully understand most of the lens concepts and the basis of optics like index of refraction, Snell's Law, etc.

Knowing this, what is the process of designing a lens, and where do I start? If you could provide any resources that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd expect that virtually all lens design and analysis these days is done with optical design software like [Zemax](http://www.radiantzemax.com/en/design/) or [Code V](http://www.opticalres.com/cv/cvprodds_f.html). Unfortunately, these products are priced for people and companies that make a (substantial) living working in the field. However, I have come across an optical design tool for Windows called [OSLO](http://www.sinopt.com/) that offers a [free version](http://www.lambdares.com/education/oslo_edu/) with reasonable limitations. I've just downloaded it, and it comes with some relatively simple lenses in its library, like a Petzval 50mm f/1.8. It doesn't look like the easiest software to get started with, but there are some users' guides on the download page.

[image: Screenshot of Petzval lens in OSLO]

Comment: Wow that actually is an incredibly awesome program. I just played around with it for half an hour and it seems pretty self explanatory as far as the simple functions.